# Grails localization, Number input

Tags: grails, localization, number-formatting

I have a Grails web application running on a german localized machine.

How does Grails determine the language to use? From the webbrowser? From the systems setting? Is this changeable with altering the language used for the ui (eg with this one: http://grails.org/plugin/lang-selector)? If not, how is it changeable?

Reason is that (seldom) i have users that access the webapp via (english) terminalserver. And there is some strange behaviour with number input (comma, dot, ...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/i18n.html

> By default the user locale is detected from the incoming
>   Accept-Language header. However, you can provide users the capability
>   to switch locales by simply passing a parameter called lang to Grails
>   as a request parameter:
>
> /book/list?lang=es
>
> Grails will automatically switch the user's locale and store it in a
>   cookie so subsequent requests will have the new header.

Answer (score 2):

Also you can configure the default locale as follows. Place

```
beans = {
    localeResolver(SessionLocaleResolver) {
        defaultLocale = new Locale("ru", "RU")
        java.util.Locale.setDefault(defaultLocale)
    }
}
```

in the resources.groovvy file